# Copy XML data from .wav file

Tags: xml, vb.net

Have audio files that have had XML data written inside of them by a 3rd party application. I can open the files in a text editor and see the XML data.

```
  <DSWork xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DSWork.xsd"> 
      <More Data...>
  </DSWork>DCRC
```

Trying to create a VB.Net application to copy the XML data to an XML file. Each time I try to clone the XML information it errors because line 1 character 1 is not valid XML data.

```
Public Sub ReadWav(Path As String)
    'Read .wav file and copy xml data to a new file
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.LoadXml(Path) 'Error Here: 

    'Dim root As XmlNode = doc.FirstChild

End Sub
```

> An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1,
>   position 1.

Comment: Post your VB.NET code

Comment: Error and code added.

Answer (score 0):

See code below.  An xml file must start with "

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
               "<DSWork xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/DSWork.xsd\">" + 
               "</DSWork>";

            string header = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Root>{0}</Root>", input);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: This is not an XML File I'm only trying to get XML Data from the end of a wav file. Error and code added

Comment: I'm now trying to set up as XmlTextReader Function but has the same issue. Also, I can't seem to find a good sample of async as an option, which seems to be the way to get around it.

Comment: It is not an sync issue.  I'm not sure how you actually got the xml that you posted.  But you have to extract the xml and then use the code I posted.  The .wav is binary so usually you have to  Encoding.UTF8.GetString() method to convert the byte array to a string.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\scan_os_alert.wav";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Wave wave = new Wave();
            wave.GetWaveStructure(FILENAME);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(wave.xml);

        }
    }
    public class Wave
    {
        public string error { get; set; }
        public UInt32 fileLength { get; set; }
        public UInt32 waveFormatChunkLength { get; set; }
        public UInt16 pcmFormat { get; set; }
        public UInt16 channels { get; set; }
        public UInt32 samplePerSecond { get; set; }
        public UInt32 bytesPerSecond { get; set; }
        public UInt16 blockAllign { get; set; }
        public UInt16 bitsPerSample { get; set; }
        public UInt32 dataLengthChunk { get; set; }
        public string xml { get; set; }


        public Wave GetWaveStructure(string filename)
        {
            error = "";

            Stream stream = File.OpenRead(filename);
            BinaryReader bReader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

            //string sInput = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length));
            //int index = sInput.IndexOf("<?xml version=\"1.0\"");

            string riff = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bReader.ReadBytes(4));
            if (riff != "RIFF")
            {
                error = "File Does not contain RIFF";
                return this;
            }
            fileLength = bReader.ReadUInt32(); ;

            string wave = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bReader.ReadBytes(4));
            if (wave != "WAVE")
            {
                error = "File Does not contain WAVE";
                return this;
            }

            string fmt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bReader.ReadBytes(4));
            if (fmt != "fmt ")
            {
                error = string.Format("File Does not contain fmt");
                return this;
            }
            waveFormatChunkLength = bReader.ReadUInt32();

            if (waveFormatChunkLength != 16)
            {
                error = "Wave Format Chunk Length is not 16";
                return this;
            }

            pcmFormat = bReader.ReadUInt16();
            channels = bReader.ReadUInt16();
            samplePerSecond = bReader.ReadUInt32();
            bytesPerSecond = bReader.ReadUInt32();
            blockAllign = bReader.ReadUInt16();
            bitsPerSample = bReader.ReadUInt16();

            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bReader.ReadBytes(4));
            if (data != "data")
            {
                error = "Does not contain data block";
                return this;
            }
            dataLengthChunk = bReader.ReadUInt32();

            UInt32 xmlOffset = dataLengthChunk + 8; 
            bReader.ReadBytes((int)xmlOffset);
            uint xmlLength = fileLength - dataLengthChunk;
            xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bReader.ReadBytes((int)xmlLength));

            return this;
        }
    }
}
​
```